# How update an individual database record by ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, record

I've been running through the ASP.Net MVC C# Movie Database tutorial, but been trying to make a few minor changes to help learn what bits do what. I will add that I am a total beginner.

I have a page with a small form and a button, when I fill out the form and click submit the data in the form updates a pre-determined record in the database table.

In the controller code how do I specify a individual record? Assuming the table will only ever have one record in it, which is going to get updated periodically with new information?

I guess it is something to do with these two lines in the code:

```
            db.Entry(data).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
```

I'm just not sure how to specify the record individually so it gets updated? The record will have an ID number (for example the ID will be "1").

The bit of code that will do the updating as it stands:

```
// POST: /Data/Update/

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(Data data)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(data).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(data);
    }
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# MVC" and such. that's what the tags are for.

Comment: What tutorial? http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application explains this in detail, please complete that tutorial.

Comment: I have similar question (with an answer).
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775503/proper-way-to-update-entity-from-controller-edit-action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF need to know which row to update in the database.
If the "ID" property wasn't bound from request, you need to set it explicitly in your code:

```
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        data.Id = 1; //EF need to know which row to update in the database.
        db.Entry(data).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitriy, unfortunately that didn't update the record for some reason (no error, clicking the button just didn't actually do anything). There are no errors when building the project in Visual Web Developer either. I can provide the code used in the View that is used if that might help? (the database is called "data.sdf", and the table in the database with the record is called "Data" - sorry, I know this is not right, but I am still learning...)

Comment: Try to run the debugger and set a breakpoint at the line "if (ModelState.IsValid)" to check whether the code is executed at all. Walk through the code with the debugger, look at entity property values​​. Are they correct?

Comment: Thank you Dmitriy, you are right, it doesn't appear that the code is getting executed. I have a View called "Update" (it is located in the View folder "Data/Update") which holds the HTML and form, with a button to commit the changes, however that button doesn't appear to do anything. The button simply has this code: <input type="submit" value="Save" /> It seems that the code isn't being called... now I'm really lost! lol

Comment: Thank you for your help Dmitriy, I figured out why the code wasn't executing (because the button had the wrong value) and your code change above updated the record perfectly. Many thanks again.