# Proper way to update entity from controller Edit action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

**Controller**

First I tried this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(JournalEntry journalentry)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(journalentry).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = journalentry.Journal.JournalId });
    }
    return View(journalentry);
}
```

Error was thrown in `SaveChanges()`:

> Error Message: "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an
>   unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or
>   deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager
>   entries."

I looked at the `journalentry` entity and noticed that its JournalEntryId was 0, but all the other properties were set correctly.  Therefore, I changed it to this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, JournalEntry journalentry)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        journalentry.JournalEntryId = id;
        db.Entry(journalentry).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = journalentry.Journal.JournalId });
    }
    return View(journalentry);
}
```

Everything looked to save correctly, but is this the correct way to save the entity?

Comment: The proper way to update an entity from the view is a misnomer because you shouldn't be doing that in the first place.

Comment: @Dismissile - I changed the title.  Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Same thing. You should never do this. You should create a view model and put any data access in a service layer. You should never really use your database entities as the models for your views.

Comment: Please go through the excellent MVC/EF tutorial which shows the correct way to do this. see http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: @Rick.Anderson-at-Microsoft.com - OK.  That's the one I haven't gone through yet.  Since everyone is suggesting I use view models, I hope this link recommends those...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you could rename the `JournalEntryId` property in your `JournalEntry` view model to `Id` and then the default model binder will automatically populate it for you so that you don't have to write the following line:

```
journalentry.JournalEntryId = id;
```

and your first code snippet will work because the Id property will be populated with the value from the route.

Or if for some reason you cannot rename the property on your view model (actually I know the reason => you are not using any view models at all but you are passing your domain entities directly to the view which is bad but subject to another question), you could use a hidden field in your form:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.JournalEntryId)
```

or modify your `Html.BeginForm` declaration to include the parameter as query string argument:

```
@Html.BeginForm("Edit", "SomeController", new { JournalEntryId = Model.JournalEntryId }, FormMethod.Post)
{
    ...        
}
```

Comment: Oh, ya, I added @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.JournalEntryId) and now it works without passing in ID.

Comment: What's wrong with passing in model?  All the asp.net/mvc sample projects like MvcMusicStore pass it straight in.  There are only a few cases when they don't in that app.

Comment: @白ジェームス, as I said, that's subject to another question. But basically it is preferred to design specific classes for your views. Those classes are called view models. They correspond exactly to the requirements of a given view. For example in order to show some view you might need information from different domain models. So you build a view model aggregating this information. Same stands true for action input parameters => they should always be view models.

Comment: Dimitov - Oh, if the view needs more information than a single model object can provide that makes sense.  In most cases this will be the case.  Good explanation.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, what do you mean by view models? I've the same problem, could you help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907277/error-dbentityvalidationexception-when-save-editted-entity