# Optimistic Concurrency issue when Updating in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, automapper

In MVC3, Entity Framework project, I'm using a ViewModel in Edit View (and AutoMapper to map Objects).

When calling `db.SaveChanges();` (in Edit View) gives an error,

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
>   of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made
>   easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See
>   the InnerException for details

Inner exception is,

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

I serached the web for this error message and now I guess this is **Optimistic Concurrency** issue, cused by one to many relationships defined in *Post* model,

> Post.Postedby -> User
>
> Post.Author -> Author

(This may be due to, the Post model I'm trying to update is detached and has no existing values when calling `SaveChanges`)

**Models**

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual User PostedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public virtual Guid UserId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(PostEditViewModel postEditViewModel, FormCollection form)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var post = Mapper.Map<PostEditViewModel, Post>(postEditViewModel);
        db.Entry(post).State = EntityState.Modified;
        string authorId = form["AuthorId"];
        post.Author = GetAuthorById(Convert.ToInt32(authorId));
        post.PostedBy = GetUserByName(User.Identity.Name);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
        return View(postEditViewModel);
 }
```

Please help me to solve this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this in Edit View fixed the issue :)

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
```

Learned from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775503/proper-way-to-update-entity-from-controller-edit-action/9775533#9775533)